# Microsoft Reporting Services not showing multiple sections

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I come from crystal reports, but this report is killing me in Microsoft Reporting Services, all I want to do is to show the report as follows

```
DATE      |  CCTYPE         |     AMOUNT
01/01/2011|AMERICAN EXPRESS | $403.00
01/01/2011|DISCOVER         | $235.00


DATE      |  CCTYPE         |     AMOUNT
01/02/2011|AMERICAN EXPRESS | $321.00
01/02/2011|DISCOVER         | $453.00
```

So for every different dat it show show the table.. My   issue is that it only shows one date.. In crystal if you add this in the design part of the report it will display it like this but I am not sure how to do this in rdcl.

I just dragged a Matrix on the report area added the fields but only shows one table although my dataset when debugging has 19 records in it.

I googled it but could not find anything related yet.

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure (unless you're using SQL Server 2000), you mean _SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)_ or are you talking about something completely different?

Comment: The extension of the report is .rdcl, is that the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you will need to add grouping into your report. On your Matrix Table, right click on the row selector on the left side, then select 'Add Row Group'. For your 'Group On' Field, select your Date field.